# Find in a collection based on an array in user's profile

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-helper

Sorry if this is a basic question, I'm relatively new to javascript and Meteor.

I'm trying to create a recommended page that recommends sites that you have upvoted. It takes the tags that are on the post, and puts them into the user profile under 'tags' as an array.

```
var websiteTags = Websites.findOne(website_id, {fields: {tag: 1} });
var getTags = websiteTags.tag;
Meteor.users.update(this_user, {$addToSet: {"profile.tags": getTags}});
```

Then under the templates helper, I'm trying to return a list of websites that have the tags equal to what is in the users profiles.

```
Template.user_recommended_list.helpers({
    websites:function(){
    var usersTags = Meteor.user().profile.tags;
        return Websites.find({tag: usersTags});
    }
});
```

If I add an index number like: `Meteor.user().profile.tags[0]`, it will work, but I need to query multiple user tags against the website tag list.

I've tried looping through the users tags then return each value to the page, but it wouldn't work. What's the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `$in` operator in your mongo query:

```
return Websites.find({tag: {$in: usersTags}});
```